# Memory leak in Flux, but where?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, project-reactor

My application consists of a rather complex system of `Flux` and `Mono` chains.
When running the program I can detect a memory leak using VisualVM.

The problem is that, allthough I can clearly see which instances are causing the memory issues, the reference tree of these instances, due to the nature of the reactive code, is pretty much opaque to me. See the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of reference tree in VisualVM]

So my question is: Is there a way to read this tree? Can I tell where the memory leak is occuring, or at least in which operator?

As the reference tree mentions a `PublishOnSubscriber` I removed all instances where I explicitly called `.publishOn`, but without success.

Comment: Can you whittle your code down to a [mcve] that still leaks?

Comment: That's the issue - I can't tell where it leaks, so I can't make a reproducible example without reproducing my entire application.

Comment: You just need to tell *if it's leaking* to start with. Then you can remove more and more of your application until you get the smallest example that still seems to leak.

Comment: Reverse engineering an entire production-grade application is a lot to ask. That's why I am not asking for a fix, I am asking for help understanding the reference tree. I believe that it could provide the necessary information to me.

Comment: This might help a little in reading the stack trace: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_the_typical_reactor_stack_trace

Answer (score 0):

A memory leak could be a sign of a Processor configured with an unbounded queue with no subscribers. The visual vm screenshot shows "queue" in the path which is why I am suggesting this.

The following will cause a memory leak:

```
UnicastProcessor<Integer> subject = UnicastProcessor.create();
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 400000000; i++) {
    Integer g = Integer.valueOf(i);
    subject.onNext(g);
    if(j++ > 100000) {
        j = 0;
        long memoryUsage = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println(memoryUsage / 1024 / 1024);
    }
}
```

Calling UnicastProcessor.create() uses an unbounded queue by default. Since there are no subscribers, items accumulate in the queue. Solution is simply to make sure the processor has a subscriber, like this:

```
        UnicastProcessor<Integer> subject = UnicastProcessor.create();
---->   subject.subscribe();
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 400000000; i++) {
            Integer g = Integer.valueOf(i);
            subject.onNext(g);
            if(j++ > 100000) {
                j = 0;
                long memoryUsage = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
                System.out.println(memoryUsage / 1024 / 1024);
            }
        }
```